# Hardwood floors maintaining a stubborn stain or mark after drum sanding

Tags: hardwood-floor

Working on a 1920 built house in Southeastern PA and having a hard time getting the hardwood floors to bring these dark spots out, visible below:
[image]

It sort of looks as though a throw rug was tossed down many years ago and for a very long time. I've sanded a particular spot repeatedly and can't get the mark to go away. I just as quickly assume it's there forever, which is OK, as there are ways around it. But I figured I'd ask here first what the problem could be.

Comment: The area rug was a sunblock for that part of the floor.  What grit have you cut the floor with?

Comment: Hi @Kris I made my initial passes with 36 grit via drum sander.

Comment: https://www.peteshardwoodfloors.com/Kadee-s-Q-A/dark-wood-under-an-old-rug.html.    This site is great fir hardwood flooring advice.

Comment: Typically Oxalic acid returns wood back to its natural color. The hard part is dealing with all the water to rinse with. I have used it many times and it works well, but most times was outside. I had only used it one time inside, it helped and because it was a small spot, the water as easy to contain. Yours is over a much larger area and would be a logistical nightmare trying to keep the water from saturating into the subfloor below and swelling everything up...